# How to change report via radio group in Oracle APEX using if statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to dynamically change what a report displays based on what is selected in a radio group.

```
   if :p33_RG = 'Daily' then
        select project_name, to_char(date_sys, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as Day,      
    sum(BATCH.RECORDS_NUMBER) as Count_of_Documents
    from BATCH
    where date_sys between :P33_START_DATE and :P33_END_DATE
    group by project_name, to_char(date_sys, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
   else if
    :p33_RG = 'Weekly' then
    select project_name, to_char(TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as WEEK, 
    sum(BATCH.RECORDS_NUMBER) as Count_of_Documents
    from BATCH
    where date_sys between :P33_START_DATE and :P33_END_DATE
    group by project_name, TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW');
   end if;
```

however I am getting multiple errors when I try to run this. Any suggestions on how I can change the script?

Answer (score 1):

`IF-THEN-ELSE` belongs to PL/SQL. In a report, you need SQL.

One option is to use `case` expression:

```
select 
  project_name,       
  sum(BATCH.RECORDS_NUMBER) as Count_of_Documents
  --
  case when :P33_RG = 'Daily' then
            to_char(date_sys, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
       when :P33_RG = 'Weekly' then
            to_char(TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  end as datum
from BATCH
where date_sys between :P33_START_DATE and :P33_END_DATE
group by 
  project_name, 
  case when :P33_RG = 'Daily' then
            to_char(date_sys, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
       when :P33_RG = 'Weekly' then
            to_char(TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  end;
```